# Group RecyclerView items in CardViews

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm making a blood pressure tracker for practice purposes where the user can store their blood pressure data. I plan to group the values by day (so a card contains measurements for a day). 
I have a `RecyclerView` setup and I can fill it with seeded data alright. I just have no idea how to group them in `CardView`s.

From the `Fragment` I tried this:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DataListViewModel::class.java)
        bpList = viewModel.data
        val bpAdapter = BpListAdapter(bpList)
        bpData.adapter = bpAdapter
        bpData.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        val dataByDay = bpList.groupBy { it.date.dayOfYear() }
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

        for (k in dataByDay.keys) {
            var card = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bp_day_card, bpData, false);
            for (v in dataByDay[k]!!) {
                card.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cw).addView(bpAdapter.itemViews[bpList.indexOf(v)])
            }
        }
    }
```

which resulted in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do create a custom item view layout with cardview as container layout and then inflate the layout in onCreateViewHolder() of adapter and bind the respective fields data in onBindViewHolder() of adaptor.